# Join 2 columns from the same table into a new column but in seperate rows

Tags: sql

I need to find customers that have multiple applications registered.
I have done a self join and used "WITH" to make it run faster but i also had to use OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT function as my results where lined up in the same row but i needed seperate rows.

The query shows | C1:systemids |C2:cxid|C3:systemid_2|C4:Cxid.2|C5:name|C6:dates|

C6 dates are associated with a seperate table that I included in the WITH clause and they are based on column C1. Only thing is C3 has the information from the split in there and i need the dates to match with those ids too.

ex. C1 has IDs (455,455,400,403); C3ids(300,700,530,100); C5 cx names (JohnDoe,JohnDoe,MaryJane,XrayLoop)
John Doe has actually 3 unique ids associated to his name (455(fromC1), 300,700 (from C3)

I need the results from C1 and C3 to be in the same column but different rows that way i can get the date associated with those different Ids for any name that appears more than once
ex.

New COlumn |C1.C3| would now have (455,300,700,400,530,403,100)

and the names column would then change to be (JohnDoe,JohnDoe,JohnDoe,MaryJane,MaryJane,Xrayloop,Xrayloop)

meaning i have 3 unique ids for johndoe, 2 ids associate with maryjane and 2 with xrayloop.

Hope this makes sens :(